# unfortunately <app name> has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

So i've googled a lot, but i haven't found a solution yet... probally because every program is different.

So basically what this program does is, take the numbers enterd in edittext fields, and then multiply, subtract and all that good stuff with eachother. Heres my logcat

> 05-28 16:37:55.847: I/ActivityManager(274): Start proc xela.kasea.flyffresell for activity xela.kasea.flyffresell/.Main: pid=779 uid=10046 gids={50046, 1028}

So thats pretty much how that looks like, now i feel like i won't need to put the manifest in here, because i only have one class(main) and theres no way theres an error in there. note: took out package name.

Heres my class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

EditText perin, amountPrUnit, buy, sell;
ToggleButton lazy;
Button clear, submit, ret;
double ans, subAnswer;
TextView pEarned, tAmount;
int a = Integer.parseInt(perin.getText().toString());
int b = Integer.parseInt(amountPrUnit.getText().toString());
int c = Integer.parseInt(buy.getText().toString());
int d = Integer.parseInt(sell.getText().toString());

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);
    Log.i("Tag2", "This is my error msg");
    initalizer();
    lazy.setOnClickListener(this);
    clear.setOnClickListener(this);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    ret.setOnClickListener(this);
    /*String a = perin.getText().toString();
    String b = amountPrUnit.getText().toString();
    String c = buy.getText().toString();
    String d = sell.getText().toString(); */
}

private void initalizer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    perin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHowRich);
    amountPrUnit =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAmountPrUnit);
    buy = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBuying);
    sell = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSellingPrUnit);
    lazy = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbBuying);
    clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClear);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubmit);
    ret = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bReturn);
    pEarned = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEarned);
    tAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAmount);
    /*int a = Integer.parseInt(perin.getText().toString());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(amountPrUnit.getText().toString());
    int c = Integer.parseInt(buy.getText().toString());
    int d = Integer.parseInt(sell.getText().toString());*/
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.bClear:
        perin.setText("");
        amountPrUnit.setText("");
        buy.setText("");
        sell.setText("");
        lazy.setChecked(false);
        break;
    case R.id.bReturn:
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
        break;
    case R.id.bSubmit:
        pEarned.setText(c*d-(a-(b*c)));
        tAmount.setText(c*d+(a-(a-(b*c))));
        setContentView(R.layout.finish);
        break;
    case R.id.tbBuying:
        if (lazy.isChecked()){
        buy.setText("");
        double subAnswer = 0;
        int ans = 0;
        subAnswer = a/b;
        ans = (int) Math.floor(subAnswer);
        /*new Integer((int) ans).toString();
        Integer.toString(answer);*/
        buy.setText(ans);;
        }
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The logcat you posted is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Please have below

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(perin.getText().toString());
int b = Integer.parseInt(amountPrUnit.getText().toString());
int c = Integer.parseInt(buy.getText().toString());
int d = Integer.parseInt(sell.getText().toString());
```

after `initalizer();`

You are trying to use the components before initializing them...

Finally your code should look like this:

```
yourcode......
initalizer();
int a = Integer.parseInt(perin.getText().toString());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(amountPrUnit.getText().toString());
    int c = Integer.parseInt(buy.getText().toString());
    int d = Integer.parseInt(sell.getText().toString()); 

 then rest of the code
```

Comment: @user3672215 - As it helped you, please accept my response as the answer. Thanks in advance and Welcome to the world of Android Progg... :>)

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't that make it only available in the onCreate?

i had it like that originally, but got a lot of errors

Comment: No, it's available for the entire life cycle of the activity. As the onCreate() is called everytime the activity is created and It is principle to initialize the components first and then do whatever you want with those components but NOT other way around

Comment: I did this, but it still didn't work...